# Windowed applications' contents stretched out, incorrect visual mouse position

Tags: intel-graphics, integrated-graphics, windows-10-v1703, minecraft, krita

Windows 10 is giving me a hard time in certain applications: Krita and Minecraft. I'm using my processor's built-in Intel HD Graphics 530 as my GPU, and for well over a year it has had no issues running Minecraft. However, it would seem like the last Creators Update and/or Intel's drivers have changed for the worse, and I'm now experiencing the strangest issue I've seen so far.

These specific applications have a specific flaw that I could not pin down, which causes the contents of their window to become stretched out, while the interface is responding to the mouse position as if it wasn't. Here's a GIF of the change happening when creating a new canvas in Krita:

[image]

The exact same effect is observable in Minecraft release 1.6 and above, only it's there as soon as the game loads and the main menu appears. GUI elements are visibly stretched and the mouse position is being recognized where the non-stretched content would be.

[image]

I have no idea what is causing this stretching, and seeing that these 2 applications don't have much in common (as far as I could tell) I'm clueless as to what to do or where to look. The internet appears to be largely silent about this issue, Googling gave me no useful results. These are the only 2 applications where I could observer this effect.

I run a single-monitor setup, but previously there was a second monitor on the system that I've since removed. I'm using Intel's latest (15.45.19.4678) graphics driver from Intel's Driver Update Utility, and Java is as up to date on my machine as it can be. I'm well and truly stuck.

Comment: disable the DPI scaling for the programs

Comment: @magicandre1981 My Settings app says that the "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" setting is on "100% (Recommended)"

Comment: try to run the applications in Win7 compatibility mode

Comment: @magicandre1981 Unfortunately that does not fix it either.